# Can we start a user-defined service from the broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing an application for mobiles and tablet in Android. **I'm using Android 2.2**

In broadcast receiver, we can put some simple process (small process/small running module code snippet). It is not suited for long running process/Long running module like **gps location capturing**,etc.

Can we start a service (user defined service - not a Android service) from  the broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can start a service from `BroadcastReceiver`. You actually need `Context` to start a `Service`. For example:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```